# while loop strange and unstable behavior in a jitted function

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, spyder, numba

I found that when the index of a `numpy` array will go out of bound inside a while-loop in a `njit` decorated function, the way the function handles the while loop can quite weird, and I am not sure why it happens.

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np


def func1(v):
    i= 0
    K= v[-1]+1
    while v[i] < K:
        i+=1
    return i

@njit        
def func2(v):
    i= 0
    K= v[-1]+1
    while v[i] < K:
        i+=1
    return i

x= np.arange(2)
result2 = func2(x)
result1 = func1(x)
```

Here is a short summary of the results:

1)  `func2` won't raise `IndexError`

2)  `func2` returns different results(like sometimes it is `4`; sometimes `5`,`9`,`12`, etc, basically unstable output) every time we run the file in the console (I am using `ipython` version `7.8.0`)

I am not sure why and how this happens(could be due to `numba` or `spyder` or `ipython` issues or it could be that my cpu is broken beyond repair) which is why I am asking for help here.

---

Note: I am using:

- Anaconda's distribution of python, python version `3.7.4`,
- spyder version `3.3.6`,
- ipython version `7.8.0`,
- numba version `0.45.1`
- OS windows 10 64-bit

Comment: On Windows 7, CPython 3.6.0 and numba 0.45.1 I can reproduce the fact that jitted func2 doesn't raise error, but in my case it always returns 2 (the index where the exception must be raised).

Comment: On Fedora 29 (kernel 5.2.11), using just the default Python REPL, your decorated `func2` always returns `2`, but likewise no `IndexError` was raised.

Comment: I am thinking it could be a problem on my end(maybe it is the `spyder`, maybe it is the `ipython`). ON a side note, both of my desktop and laptop generate the same result though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numba does not do bounds checking on Numpy arrays for performance reasons. There is currently work to turn it on optionally (https://github.com/numba/numba/pull/4432). When you go outside of the bounds of the array you will get whatever is in memory at the location or possibly seg fault.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of Numba before, but never used it myself.

Here are the results of some messing around with it (version 0.45.1) just now.

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(2)

@njit        
def func2(v):
    i = 0
    k = v[-1]+1
    while v[i] < k:
        i += 1
    return i

@njit
def func3(x):
    return x[2]



func2(x)  # returns 2, but no error raised

func3(x)  # returns 32, no error raised 
func3(np.array([0]))   # returns 32, no error raised

func2([0, 1])  # IndexError raised
func3([0, 1])  # IndexError raised
```

So to me, the bug looks to be the result of some sort of interaction between Numba's jit and Numpy arrays, since normal Python lists behave as expected.